# DataProvider - getSubresource on API Platform

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I would like to use the `DataProvider` of a `subresource` to change some data in the database.
But when I do it like this, it enters an infinite loop? How to stop it?

```
<?php
namespace App\DataProvider;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\SubresourceDataProviderInterface;

class MessageDataProvider implements SubresourceDataProviderInterface
{
    private $subresourceDataProvider;

    public function __construct(SubresourceDataProviderInterface $subresourceDataProvider)
    {
        $this->subresourceDataProvider = $subresourceDataProvider;
    }
    public function getSubresource(string $resourceClass, array $identifiers, array $context, string $operationName = null)
    {
        return $this->subresourceDataProvider->getSubresource($resourceClass, $identifiers, $context, $operationName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on this link

https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2816#issuecomment-494579509

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataProvider;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\RestrictedDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\SubresourceDataProviderInterface;
use App\Entity\Note;

class NoteSubresourceDataProvider implements RestrictedDataProviderInterface, SubresourceDataProviderInterface
{
    private $alreadyInvoked = false;
    private $subresourceDataProvider;

    public function __construct(SubresourceDataProviderInterface $subresourceDataProvider)
    {
        $this->subresourceDataProvider = $subresourceDataProvider;
    }

    public function getSubresource(string $resourceClass, array $identifiers, array $context, string $operationName = null)
    {
        $this->alreadyInvoked = true;

        $collection = $this->subresourceDataProvider->getSubresource($resourceClass, $identifiers, $context);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return !$this->alreadyInvoked && Note::class === $resourceClass;
    }
}
```

Edit: I made two examples using `SubresourceDataProviderInterface`

https://github.com/aratinau/api-platform-pagination#seventh-example--simple-dataprovider-using-subresourcedataprovider

https://github.com/aratinau/api-platform-pagination#eighth-example-use-querybuilder-in-subresource

Answer (score 4):

The class `MessageDataProvider` implements `SubresourceDataProviderInterface`, which is also a parameter in the constructor - symfony probably tries to autowire `SubresourceDataProviderInterface` by putting `MessageDataProvider` in the constructor. But in order to put `MessageDataProvider` in the constructor it has to build an instance of this type first. In order to do this the `MessageDataProvider` constructor needs to be called.. and that's how the infinite loop is created.

If you intend to inject an entity of `SubresourceDataProvider` you can configure the `MessageDataProvider` service explicitly. Link to [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-parameters)